# rails order through count on other table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting

I'm adding quiz functionality to the twitter app from the Hartl tutorial and have these Models:

User is nearly the same as the tutorial:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed

  has_many :takens, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :questions, through: :takens
end
```

Taken is a table of Question ids to User ids:

```
class Taken < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question

end
```

nothing interesting in Question:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category, :correct, :option1, :option2, :option3, :qn
end
```

I want to be able to show followed_users and followers in order of the number of tests they have taken. In the console this can be had through:

```
User.find_by_id(1).question_ids.count
```

Then I can do something like:

```
User.find_by_id(1).followers.first.question_ids.count
```

in the console to get the count for a single follower.

I feel like I'm almost there.

How do I sort the followers and followed_users through their 'takens' count? (I was also looking at cache_count, which at first seemed promising, but might not be what I need...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby on Rails does not provide an object oriented mechanism to perform this; you have to write the SQL yourself. In your case, I'd say that the following line SHOULD work:

```
User.find_by_sql("SELECT users.*, COUNT(questions.id)
 AS c FROM users, questions WHERE questions.user_id = users.id
 GROUP BY users.id ORDER BY c DESC")
```

I don't have the actual tables in front of me, so I can't be sure that this is actual valid SQL, but hopefully it should work.

**EDIT**: There were a few syntax errors with my SQL but they've been fixed. Note that I'm assuming that your tables are called `users` and `questions`. They may differ for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. My tables are indeed named that way. Where does this go? Can I somehow put it in the User model so that it becomes the default sort? Or, should I just put the above line in a controller to give me a users array?

Comment: You could perhaps define a method in your model such as "sort_by_questions_taken" which just calls that line of code, and then in your controllers you can just use User.sort_by_questions_taken

Comment: Your sql didn't work, but you certainly pointed me in the right direction! Playing around with the sqlite got me this one which does (in case anyone has a similar problem one day): SELECT users.*
FROM users INNER JOIN takens
ON users.id = takens.user_id
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY count(takens.user_id) DESC

Comment: For future reference, this is the sql I went with: `SELECT fo_ed.* FROM (SELECT users.* from users INNER JOIN relationships ON users.id = followed_id WHERE follower_id = (#{id})) fo_ed LEFT JOIN takens ON fo_ed.id = takens.user_id GROUP BY fo_ed.id ORDER BY count(takens.user_id) DESC`. It gives followed (and followers by swapping follower_id and followed_id in the inner SELECT), excludes the user themselves _and_ returns it in order of number of tests taken (whew!)